# Erro no classlist.toggle

Tags: javascript, html

estou com um problema ao adicionar classes via js, para alguns inputs são acrescentadas as clases que quero, para outras não, como posso proceder ?.

PS: A função para setar atributos nessas inputs também não está funcionando.

[image: resultado que obtenho no front]

---

```js
              function appendChildSeveralTimes(parent, child, times) {
                    this.cloneChild = child;
                    this.parent = parent;
                    this.times = times;
                    var tempInput = 
                    document.createElement('input'),tempChild;
                    var x = 0,finalElement;
                  
                    while (x < times) {
                        
                        
                        tempInput.classList.toggle('inputTable');
                        tempInput.classList.toggle('mr-auto');
                        tempInput.classList.toggle('form-control');
                        var inputClone = tempInput.cloneNode();
                            
                        tempChild = child.cloneNode();
                        tempChild.appendChild(inputClone);
                        tempChild.classList.add('nota'+x);
                        
                        parent.classList.toggle('d-flex');
                        parent.classList.toggle('w-100');
                        parent.appendChild(tempChild)
                        x++;
                        tempChild = null;

                    };
                  
                  return parent;
                    
                  

              };
              
              function placeHolders(parent){
                    var inputs = parent.querySelector('.nota0');
                  inputs.classList.toggle('nome');
                  inputs.classList.toggle('nota0');
                  inputs.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Insira o Nome do aluno');
              }
              
              var $btnAddAluno = document.getElementById('addAluno');
              var $tabelAlunos = document.getElementById('tableNotas');
              
              
              $btnAddAluno.addEventListener('click',function(){
                  var trsFinal,$tempTr,$tempTd;
                  
                  $tempTr = document.createElement('tr');
                  $tempTd = document.createElement('td');
                  
                  trsFinal = appendChildSeveralTimes($tempTr,$tempTd,5)
                  
                  placeHolders(trsFinal);
                  
                  $tabelAlunos.appendChild(trsFinal);
                  
                  
                  
                  
              })
```

Comment: Aconselho ler atentamente as diretrizes da comunidade de [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Sua pergunta está muito confusa e sem detalhes, tente melhora-la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para adicionar classes use `.classList.add()` em vez de `.classList.toggle()`. Isso porque o segundo irá adicionar e remover as classes dos elementos a cada volta no laço `while` em alternância, ou seja, o primeiro input terá as classes, o segundo não, o terceiro sim, o quarto não e o quinto sim.

A função do `.toggle()` é adicionar/retirar classe cada vez que é chamado.

A solução é trocar todos os `toggle` por `add`.